# Script to compile C code

Tags: c, linux, shell, terminal

Usually if I want to compile a C program called `number_input.c` I would type

```
cc -o number_input number_input.c
```

I want to use my mac terminal to make a script so that I don't have to type that extra word. Originally I did this to save myself 1 sec of programming but ironically I've spent over 2 hrs trying to get this to work.

```
a= echo "$1" | rev | cut -c3- | rev
echo $a
cc -o $a $1
echo $1
```

This is my output:

> number_input
>
> clang: error: no input files
>   number_input.c

I can tell that the names are being inputted correctly but for some reason the `cc` command isn't taking in the value of `$1`? I am assuming that somehow the `$1` isn't directly converted into a string or something like that but I am not sure.

Comment: You should use a Makefile.

Comment: You _could_ use a Makefile. You could also use CMake, or Ninja, or bfg9000, or gyp, or...

Comment: ...or nothing, since there is only one file being compiled!

Answer (score 5):

Your error is on the first line, since you're not assigning anything to `a`:

```
a=$(echo "$1" | rev | cut -c3- | rev)
```

Would fix the problem (for well-behaved filenames, at least, since you're missing quotes further down in your script). A space after `a` means you're assigning an empty string to it and *then* running the commands in the pipeline.

Instead of going to all the effort of reversing the twice, just remove the last two characters with `${1%??}`:

```
cc -o "${1%??}" "$1"
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common tool to do this is `make`. It reads the recipes from a file named `Makefile` in the directory it is run, and performs any tasks necessary. It is smart enough to check the file timestamps to detect if or which parts of your projects need to be re-compiled. Here is an example Makefile:

```
CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -Wall -O2
LDFLAGS := -lm

PROGS   := number_input

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(PROGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGS)

$(PROGS): %: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Note that indentation in a `Makefile` must use tabs, not spaces. If you copy the above, and paste to a file, you will need to run `sed -e 's|^  *|\t|' -i Makefile` to fix the indentation.

The first three lines name the compiler used, the compiler options, and the linking options. The `-lm` linking option is not needed for your particular use case; I just included it because you will sooner or later want to use `<math.h>`, and then you do need to include the `-lm` linking option.

The `PROGS` line names your programs. You can specify more than one, just separate them by spaces.

The `.PHONY:` line tells `make` that targets `all` and `clean` are "phony", that they do not generate files of that name.

The `all` recipe, as the first recipe in a `Makefile`, is the default recipe that is followed, when you run `make`. This one tells that all programs listed in `PROGS` should be built.

The `clean` recipe (run `make clean`) removes all temporary files and compiled files from the directory -- essentially cleaning it.

The last recipe is a tricky one. It says that all the files listed in `PROGS` are each built from a file having the same name plus a `.c` suffix. The `$^` refers to the `.c` file name, and `$@` to the file name without the suffix.

If this `Makefile` were used for returning exercises via email to a teacher, I'd also add a new `.PHONY` target, `tarball`:

```
CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -Wall -O2
LDFLAGS := -lm

PROGS   := number_input
TAR     := $(notdir $(CURDIR)).tar

.PHONY: all clean tarball

all: $(PROGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGS)

tarball: clean
    rm -f ../$(TAR)
    tar -cf ../$(TAR) $(notdir $(CURDIR))/

$(PROGS): %: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Running `make` will compile `number_input`, if `number_input.c` has been modified after the last time `number_input` was compiled, or if `number_input` does not exist yet.

Running `make TAR=myname-ex01.tar tarball` removes the compiled files from the current directory, then creates a tarball of the current directory (and its subdirectories, if any) in the parent directory as `myname-ex01.tar`. If you run just `make tarball`, the tar file name will be the same as the name of the current directory, but with a `.tar` suffix.

I hope you can see why writing a `Makefile` is so useful.